# MySQL Order by CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant make it work for me.

```
ORDER BY cl.name ASC');
```

I must change to:

```
ORDER BY CASE cl.name WHEN "Nameone" THEN 0 WHEN "Nametwo" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
```

I get the result

```
1. Nameone
2. Nametwo
```

(and the rest but its not ordered by name from A-Z but it displays i think by id)

So how to make the rest result to be ordered by cl.name ASC?

Comment: double quotes `"` mean  fieldname, single quotes ( ' ) mean string. which one you need?

Comment: btw, You dont need ASC. That is the option by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a second level of sorting to your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN cl.name = 'Nameone' THEN 0
         WHEN cl.name = 'Nametwo' THEN 1
         ELSE 2 END,
    cl.name            -- add this sort condition
```

Note that adding `cl.name` as a second sorting condition will have no effect for records where the name is `Nameone` or `Nametwo`, because the name is always the same for those records.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use the `field()` function, if you like:

```
order by field(c1.name, 'Nametwo', 'NameOne') desc,
         c1.name
```

The arguments are in reverse order, because `field()` defaults to 0 when the string is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your ORDER BY clause like this.

```sql
 ORDER BY CASE cl.name WHEN 'Nameone' THEN '0' WHEN 'Nametwo' THEN '1' ELSE CONCAT('2', COALESCE (cl.name,'')) END ASC
```